# Full screen photo viewer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table set up on a website I use it to display 9 images with descriptions. I want to be able to click on an image and have it be displayed larger like in a gallery but i would like to not have it change the layout of the page.

I am just starting to work on this web page so almost any way to do this will be helpful.

Comment: The way to write code is to write code.

Comment: where you went wrong with this questions is that you are using a table to display images. Why a table when there a far more semantically correct ways to do this. Use a plugin like fancybox, lightbox, etc. and you can easily code this in less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

[Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) is a pretty commonly used one, but I'd suggest you try and build your own. It's not a terribly difficult thing to program and it will help you grow as a programmer.

Comment: Would you have any advise on how to start trying to make my own

Comment: Yeah I would check out the source code for lightbox on <a href="https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/js/lightbox.js">github</a> and read through it. Get an idea of what they're doing. Then break it down into chunks. The click event, adding an overlay, loading the bigger image, adding next and previous buttons, etc.